# Ajaxful-rating alternative Lets-rate rails gem needs ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I need this https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_ratings#letsrate plugin to have ajax. I have to logout and login every time I rate to see the results. Example app is here http://letsrate.herokuapp.com/ 
How can I make it update results instantly? ThankS

Comment: Having the same issue, let me know if you've found the answer. Thanks!